# How to validate an uploaded csv/text file with php

Tags: php, codeigniter, csv

I am using the codeigniter and I managed to create an upload system that checks for extension and size.

What I want to do now is to check if those files are tab separated and have a specific number of columns.

Anyone can point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: How about reading this first: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450345/how-to-validate-csv-file

Comment: I read it before posting the question, it only contains suggestions, but not a straight way to do it. Besides, the approach is different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the first line and use `preg_split` to split it based on the tab character.

The size of array returned should match the expected number of columns. If not, then the uploaded file is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

Use a custom callback function for the form validation. Help on this can be found [here](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/form_validation.html#callbacks).

Help for checking tab delimited [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3395267/how-to-find-out-if-csv-file-fields-are-tab-delimited-or-comma-delimited), and number of columns [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7678266/php-fgetcsv-find-number-of-columns).

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion was also useful. I don't have the reputation to vote you up :(

Comment: @sadiqxs It was needed when that question was wrote. I succesfully voted up now :)